# MariaDB 10.1 JsonGet_string

Tags: mysql, sql, json, mariadb

In one of our columns we store this example json string:

```
[{"Name":"Pay Amount","Value":"0.00"},{"Name":"Period","Value":"3"},{"Name":"Client","Value":"TestClient"},{"Name":"Our Reference","Value":""},{"Name":"Pay Type","Value":"Test"}]
```

We repeat the Names through out and the values will differ.

I've tried querying this data using JsonGet_string :

```
SELECT
    JSONGET_string(Header, "Name") Name
FROM tbl
```

but what it does it selects the first one i.e PayAmount and it only displays a list of payamount it doesn't select anything for Period, Client etc.

The result that it returns looks like this:

```
|  Name    |
|----------|
|          |
| PayAmount|
| PayAmount|
```

And it should return this:

```
|    Name     |
|-------------|
|             | 
| PayAmount   |
| Period      |
| Client      |
| OutReference|
| Pay Type    |
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Which version are you running?

Comment: the exact version is 10.1.11